# creating multiple table using phpword

Tags: php, arrays, phpword

I am working with PHPWord and am building my table from php using this instruction:

```
$table = new Table([
    'borderSize' => 4, 
    'borderColor' => 'black', 
    'width' => 15200, 
    'unit' => TblWidth::TWIP
]);
```

I would like to display three dates per table so if I have more than three dates I should have more than one table. I added ${table} in my word file and in php I added this code:

```
while (count($dates)) {
    $numberTable++;
    
    $tableDates = array_splice($dates, 0, 3);

    $this->InsertSingleComplexTable($templateOfficer, $data, $tableDates, $numberTable);
}
```

What I should add to have table per page when I export file, and in every table three dates.